# Spell checker for MS Visual Studio with autocorrect option

Tags: visual-studio, plug-in

I just started using Visual Studio, after many years of using Eclipse.

I am looking for a Spell Checker extension, especially for text in comments (a bonus if it only works in comments, and doesn't complain about code variables).

I found the most popular of them - [Visual Studio Spell Checker (VS2017 and Later)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EWoodruff.VisualStudioSpellCheckerVS2017andLater), but despite reading its [copius documentation](https://ewsoftware.github.io/VSSpellChecker/html/027d2fbc-7bfb-4dc3-b4f5-85f95fcf7629.htm), I can't seem to get it to auto correct.

That means that every time I type `teh` instead of `the`, I have to manualluy correct it.

Is there a VS spell check extension which I can tell once to always in future correct `the` to `the`?